# Is Bhagwan Vishnu's color Blue or White?

Tags: vishnu, symbolism

As per shantakaram shlok - **meghvarn** whereas as per shuklam bardharam shlok - **shashivarna**. So, What's the actual colour of Vishnu?

Comment: The sahasranāma also mentions him having suvarṇavarṇam. And he is said to be śyāma/kṛṣṇa varṇam in several śāstras, including Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa.

Answer (score 1):

The color of Vishnu Bhagavan is mentioned in Mahabharata.

**Summary**

In the Krita Yuga, He is White in colour.

In the Treta Yuga, He is Red in colour.

In the Dvapara Yuga, He is Yellow in colour.

In the Kali Yuga, He is Black in colour.

Apart from this, His form is also described as resembling many colours/complexions in his Vishwaroopa.

**[Mahabharata Vana Parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03148.htm)**

> And, O child, **in the Krita age**, there were neither gods, nor demons, nor Gandharvas, nor Yakshas, nor Rakshasas, nor Nagas. And there was no buying and selling. And the Sama, the Rich, and the Yajus did not exist. And there was no manual labour. And then the necessaries of life were obtained only by being thought of. And the only merit was in renouncing the world. And during that yuga, there was neither disease, nor decay of the senses. And there was neither malice, nor pride, nor hypocrisy, nor discord, nor ill-will, nor cunning, nor fear, nor misery, nor envy, nor covetousness. And for this, that prime refuge of Yogis, even the Supreme Brahma, was attainable to all. **And Narayana wearing a white hue (colour) was the soul of all creatures.**

> Do thou also hear from me of the character of the **Treta Yuga**. In this age, sacrifices are introduced, and virtue decreaseth by a quarter. **And Narayana (who is the Soul of all creatures) assumeth a red colour.**

> **In the Dwapara Yuga, religion decreaseth by one half. And Narayana weareth a yellow hue.**

> O son of Kunti, **in the Kali Yuga a quarter only of virtue abideth. And in the beginning of this iron age, Narayana weareth a black hue (colour).**

Further, in his Vishwaroopa, His form is also described as resembling many colours/complexions.

**[Mahabharata Shanti Parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c039.htm)**

"Bhishma said, 'Thus hymned with names that were not known to others, the Divine Narayana having the universe for his form showed himself to the ascetic Narada. His **form was somewhat purer than the moon and differed from the moon in some respects**. He somewhat **resembled a blazing fire in complexion**. The puissant Lord was somewhat of the form of Vishti. He resembled in some respects the **feathers of the parrot**, and in some a **mass of pure crystal**. He resembled in some respects **a hill of antimony** and in some a **mass of pure gold**. His complexion somewhat **resembled the coral when first formed, and was somewhat white**. In some respects that **complexion resembled the hue of gold and in some that of the lapis lazuli**. In some respects it resembled the hue of the **blue lapis lazuli and in some that of sapphire**. In some respects it resembled the **hue of the peacock's neck**, and in some that of a **string of pearls**. Bearing these **diverse kinds of hues** on his person, the eternal Deity appeared before Narada. He had a thousand eyes and was possessed of great beauty. He had a hundred heads and a hundred feet. He had a thousand stomachs and a thousand arms. He seemed to be still inconceivable to the mind. With one of his mouths he uttered the syllable Om and then the Gayatri following Om. With mind under complete control, the great Deity, called by the names of Hari and Narayana, by his other mouths, multitudinous in number, uttered many mantras from the four Vedas which are known by the name of Aranyaka. The Lord of all the deities, the great God who is adorned in sacrifices, held in his hands a sacrificial altar, a Kamandalu, few white gems, a pair of sandal, a bundle of Kusa blades, a deer-skin, a toothstick, and a little blazing fire.